# Monitoring component via LOAD

Tags: web2py

Currently I'm writing a component 'collaboration_control' for the following purpose:

Display any news written in the database by any other component. That means, if another component (even used by another user in its own environment, in collaborative way) writes a relevant entry in the table 'update_information', the collaboration control component should read and display it.

I'm loading the collaboration control component via LOAD to an empty DIV. Then the component is looking for any new relevant entries in the DB. Of course this ping mechanism produces a measurably CPU load. As a solution I just used time.sleep() for example for 5 seconds within the collaboration control component before it reloads itself for the next lookup. But during this 5 sleeping seconds all other components of that page are sleeping too :-(

Thus my question is:
How can I implement an asynchronous look-up-component in web2py?

Thanks in advance for any support!

Best regards
Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `time.sleep()`, it sounds like you are causing the Ajax request to pause on the server, forcing each request to take 5 seconds. This is not a good idea, as it will occupy a web server thread for the entire 5 seconds. Furthermore, if you are using the default file-based sessions, holding open an Ajax request for several seconds will prevent additional Ajax requests from completing because each request puts a lock on the session file. To mitigate this problem, you could explicitly unlock the session file before the 5 second pause, but there is a much better approach, which is to instead have the browser do the waiting in between making Ajax requests.

In fact, the `LOAD()` helper has built-in functionality to reload itself at specified intervals. For example:

```
{{=LOAD(..., ajax=True, timeout=5000, times='infinity')}}
```

The above will reload the component every 5 seconds (but the Ajax request will return quickly, with the waiting being done in the browser via Javascript).

Note, depending on your level of traffic, polling via Ajax every few seconds could put too much load on your server. In that case, you might consider a more efficient push-based alternative, such as web2py's [websocket_messaging](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py) functionality or something like [Nchan](https://nchan.io/).

Comment: Anthony, thanks a lot!!!

You know it: As always your answer is the solution!

Best regards,
Clemens

Comment: You're welcome. I added a note at the end suggesting an alternative approach if server load becomes a problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will keep an eye on the resulting traffic. In case it's too high a push mechanism would really be an alternative. I'm gonna keep you informed ...